# Export spreadsheet to shapefile not working

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, spreadsheet

Pretty basic, but I've never had this happen. I have a spreadsheet with X/Y which I have imported into ArcMap (all fine no issues).
However when I export it to a shapefile it is blank. If I export it to a geodatabase it works.

However if I export the feature class in the geodatabase to a shapefile its blank.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Here is a snip of the attributes:

[image]

Comment: Eliminate any characters that are not alphanumeric character or an underscore.  https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000005588

Comment: Did you conduct any analysis on the imported spreadsheet?

Comment: Avoid using field names that contain words that are considered reserved keywords, such as date, day, month, table, text, user, when, where, year, and zone.  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/fundamentals-of-adding-and-deleting-fields.htm#GUID-8E190093-8F8F-4132-AF4F-B0C9220F76B3

Comment: So what are you actually showing in your "snip", is this XY event layer built from your spreadsheet prior to any export or your Feature Class in a geodatabase?